# Error cannot post / with express and node

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am making an app with node and express, the problem is that i can send something to my database MYSQL and i can receive the data but i get an error that says cannot POST /registrarme, in the console i get a message that says POST  /registrarme 404
This is my code:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const pool = require('../database');
const helpers = require('../lib/helpers')


passport.use('local.registrarme', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'contrasena',
    passReqToCallback: true   
}, async(req,email, contrasena, done) =>{
    const { dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direccion, telefono, id_poblacion} = req.body;
    const nuevousuario  = {
        email: email,
        contrasena: contrasena,
        dni,
        nombre,
        apellido1,
        apellido2,
        direccion,
        telefono,
        id_poblacion,
    };
    nuevousuario.contrasena = await helpers.encryptPassword(contrasena);

   const result=  await pool.query('INSERT INTO PERSONAS SET ?', [nuevousuario]);
   console.log(result);
    nuevousuario.id= result.insertId;
  return done(null, nuevousuario);
}));


 passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>{
  done(null, user.id);

});


passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) =>{
   const rows = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM PERSONAS WHERE id = ?', [id]);
   done(null,rows[0]);
});
```

And this is my router code :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

//renderizar los datos
router.get('/registrarme', (req,res) =>{
    res.render('auth/registrarme')
});

//ruta para recibir los datos


router.post('/registrarme', passport.authenticate('local.registrarme',{
    succesRedirect: '/perfil',
    failureRedirect: '/registrarme',
    failureFlash: true
}))

//ruta perfil
router.get('/perfil', (req,res) =>{
    res.send('Este es tu perfil')
});


module.exports = router;
```

When i can send the items to the database i want that the page redirects me to /perfil but i get that error

Answer (score 0):

Your route seems to be missing the last function that needs to run, after all middleware.
Change it to:

```
router.post('/registrarme', passport.authenticate('local.registrarme', {
    succesRedirect: '/perfil',
    failureRedirect: '/registrarme',
    failureFlash: true
}), (req, res) => {
    console.log('registrarme route!')
})
```

Comment: It works correctly but the code doesnt do what i want, it sems now that the part of succes redirect and failure direct doesnt work so it sends the message to the console but the page keeps loading without any response althought the terms are send and receivend on the Database